# Update UIImage in UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift, uiimage

I've created a custom UITableView cell containing a UIImage and a few labels. I have tagged the UIImage as 100 and have been attempting to update it as follows:

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


let Items = ["Altitude","Distance","Groundspeed"]

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.Items.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.Items[indexPath.row]

    var CellImageView: UIImageView? = cell.viewWithTag(100) as UIImageView?
    CellImageView!.image = UIImage(named: "Airspeed")

    return cell
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

How should I be updating the UIImage? I currently get a EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error when I run my app.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if CellImageView isn't nil
just add a if statement like I done in code.This happens to you because CellImageView is nil.If you check an CellImageView is nil nothing will happen.So when you have an optional always check it before using it.I don't know what you want to do with viewWithTag.You may use a another view to load the image using `override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)`.ex

This how I did in my project

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    var secondeScene = segue.destinationViewController  as DisplayViewController
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow(){
        let selectedPhoto = photos[indexPath.row]
        secondeScene.currentPhoto = selectedPhoto
    }
```

---

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


let Items = ["Altitude","Distance","Groundspeed"]

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.Items.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.Items[indexPath.row]

    var CellImageView: UIImageView? = cell.viewWithTag(100) as UIImageView?//CellImageView is an optional
 if  CellImageView !== nil{//checking for CellImageView
    CellImageView!.image = UIImage(named: "Airspeed")
    }
    return cell
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use this

```
import UIKit
```

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

let image = UIImage(named: "Airspeed")
let Items = ["Altitude","Distance","Groundspeed"]

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.Items.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.Items[indexPath.row]

    var CellImageView: UIImageView? = cell.viewWithTag(100) as UIImageView?
    //if  CellImageView !== nil{
    //CellImageView!.image = UIImage(named: "Airspeed")
    //}
    return cell
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    var secondeScene = segue.destinationViewController  as DisplayViewController
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow(){
        let selectedPhoto = image
        secondeScene.currentPhoto = selectedPhoto


    }
```

}

This the first view and then use this for the second view

```
class DisplayViewController: UIViewController {
```

var currentPhoto : UIImage?

@IBOutlet weak var curentImage: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

```
var image = UIImage(named: currentPhoto!.filename)
curentImage.image = image



// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
```

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

This wil load the image you on another view .Link this class with view in IB

Comment: I'm just confused as to why I need the second class? Why can't I just reference my UIImageView in the first class using the ID I generated in interface builder? I would rather keep everything in the one class if I could.